# Weblogic Managed server is running, but getting error 404--not found for SOA demo application deployed on it

Tags: weblogic, managed

I have an instance of Admin server and Managed server running on my machine. Though I have started the Managed server from command prompt. Now, when I am deploying the SOA sample application "Fusion Order Demo" on Managed server, it get deployed successfully on Managed Server. I am using the Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 to deploy StoreFront module on Weblogic server instance. But when I am running the test url (`http://<hostname>:<port>/StoreFrontServiceHooks/StoreFrontService`) against the target managed server, I am getting the error 404--not found.

Following is the synopsis of the text from the Managed server log for your reference.

Service Deployment log:

```
####<20/04/2014 4:51:28 PM NZST> <Info> <EJB> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <0000KLxU8gm3z0WjLxyGOA1JKp8B000002> <1397969488233> <BEA-014021> <The EJB 'oracle.fodemo.storefront.store.service.common.StoreFrontServiceBean(Application: StoreFrontService_SDOServices, EJBComponent: StoreFrontServiceHooks.jar)' has been successfully deployed. The following remote interfaces have been bound into JNDI with the specified JNDI names:> 
####<20/04/2014 4:51:28 PM NZST> <Info> <EJB> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <0000KLxU8gm3z0WjLxyGOA1JKp8B000002> <1397969488233> <BEA-014022> <******** oracle.fodemo.storefront.store.service.common.serviceinterface.StoreFrontService is bound with JNDI name:StoreFrontServiceBean#oracle.fodemo.storefront.store.service.common.serviceinterface.StoreFrontService ********> 
####<20/04/2014 4:51:28 PM NZST> <Info> <EJB> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <0000KLxU8gm3z0WjLxyGOA1JKp8B000002> <1397969488233> <BEA-010009> <EJB Deployed EJB with JNDI name StoreFrontService_SDOServicesStoreFrontServiceHooks_jaroracle_fodemo_storefront_store_service_common_StoreFrontServiceBean_Home.> 
####<20/04/2014 4:51:28 PM NZST> <Info> <Deployer> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <0000KLxU8gm3z0WjLxyGOA1JKp8B000002> <1397969488234> <BEA-149060> <Module StoreFrontServiceHooks.jar of application StoreFrontService_SDOServices successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server bam_server1.> 
####<20/04/2014 4:51:28 PM NZST> <Info> <Deployer> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <0000KLxU8gm3z0WjLxyGOA1JKp8B000002> <1397969488234> <BEA-149059> <Module StoreFrontServiceHooks of application StoreFrontService_SDOServices is transitioning from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server bam_server1.>
```

Log for URL access failure:

```
####<20/04/2014 5:21:21 PM NZST> <Error> <HTTP> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001aa> <1397971281003> <BEA-101305> <[ServletContext@482182690[app:StoreFrontModule module:StoreFrontModule path:/StoreFrontModule spec-version:2.5]] Error-page location: "/faces/unexpectedErrorHandler.jspx" for the error-code: "404" causes an infinite loop condition as it throws the same code for which it has been mapped.> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:37 PM NZST> <Info> <Health> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <weblogic.GCMonitor> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-000000000000001d> <1397971297574> <BEA-310002> <62% of the total memory in the server is free> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Warning> <oracle.adf.share.ADFContext> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ac> <1397971302885> <BEA-000000> <Automatically initializing a DefaultContext for getCurrent.
Caller should ensure that a DefaultContext is proper for this use.
Memory leaks and/or unexpected behaviour may occur if the automatic initialization is performed improperly.
This message may be avoided by performing initADFContext before using getCurrent().
For more information please enable logging for oracle.adf.share.ADFContext at FINEST level.> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Info> <ServletContext-/StoreFrontModule> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ac> <1397971302887> <BEA-000000> <JspServlet error: Servlet unable to dispatch to the following requested page: The following exception occurred:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /index.jsp> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Info> <oracle.j2ee.jsp> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ac> <1397971302887> <BEA-000000> <unable to dispatch JSP page: The following exception occurred:.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /index.jsp
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.ADFJspResourceProvider.internalFromStream(ADFJspResourceProvider.java:602)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.ADFJspResourceProvider.fromStream(ADFJspResourceProvider.java:346)
    at oracle.jsp.parse.XMLUtil.getFromStream(XMLUtil.java:311)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.compileBothModes(JspPageCompiler.java:480)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.parseAndGetTreeNode(JspPageCompiler.java:457)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageInfo.compileAndLoad(JspPageInfo.java:624)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.compileAndServe(JspPageTable.java:645)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:387)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:842)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:766)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Warning> <oracle.adf.share.ADFContext> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ae> <1397971302894> <BEA-000000> <Automatically initializing a DefaultContext for getCurrent.
Caller should ensure that a DefaultContext is proper for this use.
Memory leaks and/or unexpected behaviour may occur if the automatic initialization is performed improperly.
This message may be avoided by performing initADFContext before using getCurrent().
For more information please enable logging for oracle.adf.share.ADFContext at FINEST level.> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Info> <ServletContext-/StoreFrontModule> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ae> <1397971302895> <BEA-000000> <JspServlet error: Servlet unable to dispatch to the following requested page: The following exception occurred:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /index.jsp> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Info> <oracle.j2ee.jsp> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ae> <1397971302896> <BEA-000000> <unable to dispatch JSP page: The following exception occurred:.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /index.jsp
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.ADFJspResourceProvider.internalFromStream(ADFJspResourceProvider.java:602)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.ADFJspResourceProvider.fromStream(ADFJspResourceProvider.java:346)
    at oracle.jsp.parse.XMLUtil.getFromStream(XMLUtil.java:311)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.compileBothModes(JspPageCompiler.java:480)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageCompiler.parseAndGetTreeNode(JspPageCompiler.java:457)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageInfo.compileAndLoad(JspPageInfo.java:624)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.compileAndServe(JspPageTable.java:645)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspPageTable.service(JspPageTable.java:387)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.internalService(JspServlet.java:842)
    at oracle.jsp.runtimev2.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:766)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Warning> <org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.skin.SkinFactoryImpl> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ae> <1397971302901> <BEA-000000> <Cannot find an unversioned skin for family skyros. We will use the versioned skin skyros-v1.desktop.> 
####<20/04/2014 5:21:42 PM NZST> <Info> <ServletContext-/StoreFrontModule> <Sri-HP4530s-010> <bam_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <1b7e5955c26b51de:648ed59c:1457d787ec8:-8000-00000000000001ae> <1397971302904> <BEA-000000> <JspServlet error: Servlet unable to dispatch to the following requested page: The following exception occurred:java.io.FileNotFoundException: /index.jsp>
```

I will really appreciate your help in this regard.

Thanks and regards,
Neelesh jain

Answer (score 1):

If you have obtained a 404 error from your server, it means your server is up and running. However, it is looking for the start-point of your application in the wrong place. I am assuming that your application has an entry point, say a JSP flie like main.jsp or main.jspx.

Make sure it's under proper folder.
For example, in Oracle ADF applications, files like this should be under the root ViewController project. If you put it in WEB-INF folder along with web.xml and weblogic.xml, it would also give you 404 NOT FOUND error.

I was facing this problem just now.So I Googled and landed on your question page. Anyway, I fixed my problem like that. Maybe you can too.

Comment: "Maybe" is not an answer.

Comment: No, it's not. But it's a helpful response. The OP has not provided no information about directory structure, just the stacktrace. I simply wanted to make sure the entry point of the application is under proper folder. What's wrong with that?

Comment: A helpful response should be a comment under the question, not an answer. That's what I was suggesting. But let's leave it as is and see if OP accepts your response as a valid answer.